# How do I add different background colors to multiple cells poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to add different backgrounds colors and borders to the cells of an XLS file
this is my code

```
  Row r = sh.createRow(sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
     CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
     style = wb.createCellStyle(r.getPhyscal);
     //region
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell c = r.createCell(1);
    c.setCellValue((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());


 c.setCellStyle(style);
    //sA   
     style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        c = r.createCell(2);
        c.setCellValue((String) jT1.getText() );
  c.setCellStyle(style);
```

this is the result i need

[image: Wanted Excel view]

but that is the result i have

[image: Current Excel view]

Comment: Create a different cell style for each column?

Comment: Yes Create a different cells styles colors with borders for each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new `CellStyle` for each color.

```
CellStyle orangeStyle = wb.createCellStyle(r.getPhyscal);     
orangeStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
orangeStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

CellStyle redStyle = wb.createCellStyle(r.getPhyscal);
redStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
redStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

..
```

and attach the fitting style to each affected cell

Comment: Create a different celsl style colors with borders for each column i write in file xls

Comment: For each color, you need a new `CellSty!e` object. In your sample code, you create just one and change its properties. By doing that, only the last setting becomes effective, for all cells with that style. Don't do that. Instead, create as many CellStyles as necessary, one for each distinct combination of color, font, border etc.